# Extract specific text from Internet explorer

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

i have this Html and VBA codes as shown below, i am trying to Use excel VBA to extract the name Verizon Wireless only so i used the Following excel VBA Code. But when i run it it is returning "Type:Mobile" I'm assuming this is because the Class name i used is shared by both children under that div so my questions is, is there a way to just extract the name of the carrier?

Thanks

````
-------HTML CODE-------

<div class="left-phone-info">
          <h1>(405) 482-3431</h1>
          <p class="subtext grey phone-details"><strong>Type:</strong> Mobile</p>
            <p class="subtext grey phone-details">
                <strong>Carrier:</strong> Verizon Wireless
            </p>
        </div>

------VBA CODE-------

Sub get_carrier()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument
Dim num As String

num = Range("B1").Value
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.navigate ("https://www.whitepages.com/phone/1-405-482-3431")
ie.Visible = True

Do
DoEvents
Loop Until ie.readyState = 4
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)


Set ht = ie.document
Set tags = ht.getElementsByClassName("subtext grey phone-details")
For Each tagx In tags
            MsgBox tagx.innerText
        Exit For
    Next

End Sub ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` should be returning a collection.  In your example, it would be a collection with 2 items.

Try accessing the second item by index with:

`Set tags = ht.getElementsByClassName("subtext grey phone-details")(1)`

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer , i tried that but it returns Error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @Theo O Your `For` loop is causing that error.  `tags` is a single element, you cannot  loop through it. Remove the loop and use `MsgBox tags.innerText` instead of `tagx`

Comment: @Theo O `ht`and `tags`can also be removed if you read the element directly with `MsgBox ie.document.getElementsByClassName("subtext grey phone-details")(1).innerText`

Comment: Was very helpful thanks much. i got it to work and even stripped the unnecessary text strings leaving just the carrier name and entering that in the designated cell my resulting code became


`Dim tags As IHTMLElement
Set ht = ie.document
Set tags = ht.getElementsByClassName("subtext grey phone-details")(1)
            cell2 = Replace(tags.innerText, "Carrier:", "")
            ActiveSheet.Range("B2") = Trim(cell2)`
            
            

End Sub

Worked like Magic all thanks to you